# Interaction effect and collinearity: important or not? Influence of precipitation on foraging behavior?

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, multicollinearity, biostatistics

I am facing a pretty straightforward case. I wish to test whether precipitation, represented as interaction effect between two numerical variables (*number of strong showers* x *highest rainfall* recorded over a month) affect the foraging behavior of an animal (i.e. *number of prey eaten*) at different locations with varying prey availability (i.e. *location ID*: categorical variable). I tried fitting in R both a linear model (lm) and a mixed effect model (lmer) with location respectively as explanatory variable and random effect. For the latter model for instance, I get the following result:

```
lmer(eaten ~ nshowers*maxprec + (1|location), REML=FALSE)
                  Estimate    df        p-value
(Intercept)        1297       24.95     0.43
nshowers         -23350       19.95     0.012 *
maxprec             711       20.74     0.177
nshowers*maxprec  32117       19.93     0.0005***
```

(Note that I have scaled the explanatory variables to allow to compare their effects.)

Now my problem is the following: there is collinearity between nshowers and maxprec (r=0.47) and obviously also between the interaction effect (nshowers*maxprec) and the two related variables, esp. with nshowers (r=0.8 and VIF > 40).

My question is therefore simply: do these two collinearities matter here? (And also, how should the coefficients for nshowers and nshowers*maxprec, which are of similar magnitude but opposing signs, be interpreted?)